# url rewriting synthax with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am on apache 2 and I would know if my htacces is correct

my url are for example :

```
localhost/test/boutique/index.php
localhost/test/boutique/index.php/language,en
localhost/test/boutique/index.php/Products/Description/products_id,1
localhost/test/boutique/index.php/Products/Description/products_id,2/language,fr
```

What is the best approach for a good url like above
In suppose index.php must deseapear to hav someting like that

```
localhost/test/boutique/Products/Description/products_id,1
```

I try this but it does'nt work

```
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/test/boutique/index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `/test/boutique/` is a real directory, you can use these rules inside `/test/boutique/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/boutique/

# remove index.php if entered directly by clients
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$).* index.php/$0 [L,NC]
```